# Best way to implement Lightbox over an existing React hooks gallery

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an implemented search bar that returns images from an api.
it shows them as squares in front of you.
i want to implement a lightbox gallery on top of it that brings the high res from the api.
I will like to know the best way to implement this feature

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [react-image-lightbox](https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-image-lightbox/blob/master/README.md) some time ago when it was in it's early stages. It seems like a robust lib which does exactly what you want now.